# brew - mysql is not available unless the installation account is signed on

Tags: macos, mariadb, homebrew

I have set up an environment (apache/php/mariadb) on a Mac using Homebrew.

All is working great as long as the account I used to perform the install is signed onto the Mac. If the Mac is started and no account has logged on, then I’m unable to access the database over the network. If one of the other accounts on the mac log on, I still cannot access the database, even thought it is up and running. It is not until I actually sign on to the Mac as the account who performed the installation can i access the database.

My goal is to have an environment where multiple people can access the Mac from the network. I want the Mac to start up, but I do not want to require anyone to sign onto the Mac for the environment to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew is, by design, running all services under the user account. If you want to run a system service, you probably better have to install the different applications using the standard way.